# Android cell broadcast api?

Tags: android, sms, cell, broadcast

I saw a cell broadcast program which uses `android.telephony.SmsCbMessage` and `android.content.BroadcastReceiver`. I tried to compile in NetBeans, but it doesn't find `_SmsCbMessage_` class. I have the latest Android 2.3.4 libs.

Can you tell what's happening? Is `android.telephony.SmsCbMessage` really gone? Or do I need some kind of seperate libs for it?